# ng-click modal or dialog confirmation

Tags: angularjs

how can I add a modal or confirmation dialog before deleting an element?

Html

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger px-3" ng-click="removeClient(cliente)">Eliminar</a>
```

Js

```
$scope.removeClient = function(id) {
    $scope.clientesPotenciales.$remove(id);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in angular modal. But the Bootstrap CSS framework has a modal implementation.

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

You can implement it directly or use the `ui-bootstrap` library from Angular UI.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

And for a non-bootstrap alternative...

http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/#

Comment: I tried to use ui-bootstrap but when I implement something it happens and it does not load the site, it must be an incompatibility problem, I do not know. `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'firebase', 'ui-bootstrap']);`

Comment: The ui-bootstrap solution is only if you're using Bootstrap for your site anyway. If you are not, try the ngDialog library.

Comment: If I am using the latest bootstrap version. I find it strange, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way but you sacrifice a good user interface, else go for `angular-material` or `ui-bootstrap` modal window for confirmation!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.removeClient = function(id) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
         $scope.clientesPotenciales.$remove(id);
    }  
  };
});
```

Comment: It works. It's true about UI, I'll consider it. Thank you.